# Fails to do auto compile and update in browser in some files in react js

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My folder structure :

```
 Project  
   public  -- folder
   src     -- folder
     App.js
     Containers -- folder
       Dashboard -- folder
         Dashboard.js  --- component
       BatchDetails  -- folder
         BatchDetails.js  -- component
     index.js
     AppRoutes.js
   Package.json
```

** If I do any changes in Dashboard.js then it is auto compiling and updating the browser
but I If I do any changes in BatchDetails.js then it is not auto compiling and also some few nestesd folder files also not auto compiling**

Please let me know why it is not auto compiling in some files. Thanks in Advance